# 2002/2003 PC Game about Super-soldiers winning against aliens but losing Earth coming back?

Tags: story-identification, video-games

A long time ago I remember playing a PC game around the time of HALO: COMBAT EVOLVED clones... one stood out in particular.

The story preface revolves around a war between Earth and aliens. Humans win by the skin of their teeth, but when the remains of the fleet comes back, they find that the war was a diversion and the aliens took Earth while they were away.

The commander during his speech calls his supersoldiers "his children" and the entire game is a mix between shooter, vehicular combat, squad tactics, and a light flight combat simulator to kill aliens by the hundreds.

It was interesting at the time because I remember the game letting me peek by leaning out of corners, having very tactical gameplay, and squad multiplayer with 8v8 and later I think 16v16 matches with Gamespy.

Notes: 1st/3rd person shooter, PC, game came out around 2002/2003

Comment: Could you add a year? Not everyone here might now when Halo: Combat Evolved came out.

Comment: What system(s)? PC? Playstation? Xbox?

Comment: What do you mean 1st/3rd person shooter? You could switch camera placement, or did it switch on it's own when you entered a vehicle?

Comment: It's just called Halo: Combat Evolved. The all-caps style is just a marketing thing, not the *actual* title of the game.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The game you are looking for just might be [**Breed**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breed_(video_game)), released in 2004.

[image: Cover]

> **Plot synopsis**
>
> After their year-long journey the fleet arrived at Besalius in 2604
> and swiftly engaged the Breed presence across the system. The battle
> was long and hard, as the Breed did not give up the system without a
> fight; their lack of intelligence was more than compensated by their
> ferocious nature in battle. This conflict with the Breed would come to
> be known as the Colony War.
>
> The humans resources were drastically drained during this rigorous
> fight and the USC forces are stretched to breaking point. In 2624 the
> USC forces claimed victory in Besalius, but it was not without cost –
> the colonies had been devastated and the fleet badly damaged to a
> point that only the USC Darwin was capable of making the journey back
> to Earth. Captained by Saul Richter (A legend now with over two
> hundred victories against the Breed under his belt) war weary and
> battle scarred, the ship and remaining crew began their return
> journey.
>
> In 2625 that the victorious veterans of Besalius finally returned home
> expecting a heroes' welcome. Instead, the crew of the Darwin found
> their world on fire, that in their 20-year absence, the Breed had
> conquered Earth. The Colony War on Besalius was nothing more than a
> diversionary tactic – a plan to pull the bulk of Earth's defense
> forces away, leaving it ripe for invasion. The human population had
> been enslaved or devastated, the survivors had been enslaved by the
> Breed in forced labor camps.

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]

Comment: looks the goods, I do remember it being re-released a while ago fixing most of the bugs, I want to pick that game up... maybe even do a video playthrough,

Comment: @Crashie-J I just might race you and make a couple of videos. This game looks pretty cool!

Comment: I just saw this in a thrift store yesterday. Now I kinda wish I'd picked it up.