# Looking for the name of a turn-based space strategy game released around 2000

Tags: story-identification, video-games, space

Recently I took a look at *Star Citizen*, and as I saw the space map with all the systems and the spherical music it instantly reminded me of a game I played as a teenager years ago. It was a strategic game where you start at the outer skirts of the milky way in our system Sol, and have to explore and colonize other systems, get in contact with other species etc.

It was turn-based and the main view was a three-dimensional look at the milky way with the spherical "space-like" music. The time as this game was new and I had played it must be somewhere around 1998–2004.

This is all the information I can recall, but I want to know what game it was, guess it was not that well-known because I have a hard time to find it out myself.

It was not *Master of Orion*, not *ST: Birth of the Federation*, and not *Homeworld* (which is an RTS, so does not fit the description anyway).

So has anybody an idea what game it is that I played and enjoyed back then?

Comment: This does not really fit on this site, it should be posted on Arcade (Although I am not sure if you have provided enough info for people on that Site to help)

You may want to try checking this list on wikipedia - it might contain the game you are after...
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_4X_video_games

Comment: This is on-topic, @EdHunter, and although you're right, Arcade is a better fit, they will not take these type of questions without a screenshot or something else concrete to identify.  The main problem with this is that it doesn't have a whole lot of detail.  Space setting turn-based 4X is a genre, not an ID.

Comment: @EdHunter visit [this](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319/can-i-ask-a-question-about-video-game-based-scifi-fantasy) and [this](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319/can-i-ask-a-question-about-video-game-based-scifi-fantasy) for clarification on game-ID questions

Comment: @user14111 whoops, gave the same link twice. Give me a moment to fix that..

Comment: @user14111 https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4778/19561 answers that, I think.

Comment: It's not at all obvious to me what you mean by the term "spherical music" that you use twice. Can you perhaps elaborate a bit on that? Also, do you remember what platform you played the game on? Did you have a PC or Mac. If a PC, was the game for Windows or DOS. If Windows, do you remember which version of Windows you were using at the time? That might help narrow down the date range.

Comment: @Blckknght It was on PC with Windows, must be Windows ME or Windows XP by that time. Also for the spherical music: Music with "long standing" sounds, like (electro) chill out music, but more in the direction to "invoke a mental image of space", as said the music was quite similar to the music from Star Citizen when you are in the view of the solar systems, sorry if this is quite vague...

Comment: is the atmosphere you are describing similar to the atmosphere you get when launching Spore (View of Milky Way galaxy with some relaxing music)

Comment: are you 100% certain the game starts in the Sol system?

Comment: 'Space Empires' is another game to check.  The last version (5, I think) had 3d graphics.

Comment: @Mart10 Yes, this looks and sounds similar, but the look is more detailed (especially the "moving parts" of the galaxy) in Spore. It is not 'Space Empires'. I am not 100% that you have to start in Sol, but as I remember it I always started there.

Comment: @StefanH could you pick a starting species? Did it involve resource gathering or unit/utility building (if so is there anything that brings to mind), could you trade or go to war? Can you remember great wins/defeats etc...?

Comment: @JonClements Unfornutely I am not sure about all of this (if I am I would have give those information in my post), as I remember you start as a human and do not have any choice about that, and it was mainly about research and colonization.

Comment: @StefanH Several elements in your description make me think of [Ascendancy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascendancy_(video_game)), which was around the same time period (1995) and the first I can think of with a 3D solar system map like Star Citizen.  Heavy on research and colonization.  Definitely has [spacey-sounding music](https://youtu.be/kMU5rhEZpkA?list=PLA07BEF3A42580696), and is a relatively unknown game these days.  However, it definitely wasn't the Sol system, and humans weren't even an option when [picking a species](http://www.b-sting.nl/ascendancy/species.html).

Comment: @MikeTV Interesting suggestion, but it is not this game, it looks too different.

Comment: Could it be Imperium Galactica 2?

Comment: @TommyBs YEEESSSSSSS!!!!!!!!! OMG took more than a year till we finally found it, guess this beautiful game was not very successful back then. Maybe you could write it up as an answer, so I can mark this question as answered...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Could this possibly be [Imperium Galactica 2](https://www.gog.com/game/imperium_galactica_ii_alliances)?

Originally released December 1, 1999 by Digital Reality Software / THQ Nordic GmbH.

Overview:

> Take your empire in your hands and guide it into the future. Use intrigue and spying to weaken your enemies and strengthen yourself or research and build the most powerful military force in the universe to crush whoever would oppose you. Massive battles, universe spanning empires, 3 playable campaigns and countless possibilities through custom scenarios insure you always have something to come back to. Take control, conquer the universe, and lead your species to ultimate domination… for the Imperium.
>   Construct huge cities on your terraformed planets to generate income, war machines and over 150 scientific advancements.
>   Play through three separate story-driven campaigns.
>   Over 75 planets to explore, conquer, and colonize.
>   Random events ensure that no two games are ever the same.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Yes, considering its age it looks really good, all in nice 3d rendering back then.

Comment: If I may, I know you've been here longer than me, so I don't want to sound preachy, but apparently this is your first story-id post. Hence, even if the OP has accepted your answer, could you edit in the elements (plot, screenshots, ambiance etc) which made you think that was it? For the sake of future users looking for this game, and the [general policy on story-ID answering](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9444/98028) :) cheers!

Comment: No problem, it doesn't sound preachy at all as you're correct this is my first time answering a question like this. Though I'm not sure what to fill in for at all, as the question just jogged my memory to a game I used to have and I happened to remember the name!

Comment: (1/2) Well for instance you could add the jacket, the "official syonpsis", some screenshots of the "Milky Way 3D rendering" (though those are already included in the link you provided so it's fine :) ), maybe an extract of the game soundtrack if you happen to remember which _Star Citizen_ part it was remnant of...

Comment: (2/2) Mainly things that address the keypoints given by OP, though to be honest I've not played either of these games so I'm not sure if what I say is even doable ahah :) I suggest you take a look at [this accepted video game-id answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/153752/98028), [this one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/174001/98028) and [this one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/190602/98028) for instance!

Comment: That's the trouble I don't really remember a lot of it myself, I just remember the title of the game and thought it could be it based on the description of the map - I don't remember the soundtrack either!

Comment: Let's not flood the comments and move to [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58631/the-restaurant-at-the-end-of-the-universe) shall we :)

Answer (score 4):

Possibly...

[VGA Planets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VGA_Planets)

[Galactic Civilizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galactic_Civilizations)

If you want to meander through memory lane (and maybe find this game, there were a bazzillion of them), check out this [list of turn-based strategy video games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_turn-based_strategy_video_games)

Comment: VGAPlanets is much older than 2000 and the map was 2D.  Also, each star had only one planet rather than a solar system.  And damn, I miss that game :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but those two you mentioned do not fit. I am searching through the list, but up to now I cannot find it there either.