# PlayStation 1 Game about a boy who gets amnesia

Tags: story-identification, video-games

Correct me if I am posting on the wrong Stack Exchange. I am looking for a certain game that I'm pretty sure was on PS1. Around 10 years ago, I just watched the intro of the game. It is a story where there is a boy (main character) and a girl in a town near a sea. Then suddenly tragedy strikes. When the boy wakes up, the girl is nowhere to be found and the boy has amnesia. Graphics is similar to Kingdom Hearts and alike.

Comment: What Fantasy or SciFi aspects does it have?

Comment: [gaming.SE](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/) also exists, but I believe game identification questions that rely solely on memory are considered off-topic there.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here ; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: This sounds like the start of Ocarina of Time :-)

Comment: @Valorum If it was on PS1 as the OP says, then it can't be the Ocarina of Time (OoT), as Zelda is strictly Nintendo IP ;-)

However, I agree it sounds a lot like OoT though.

Comment: @Loki we could be pedantic and go "Well the PS was originally a Nintendo/Sony joint venture, and there were the Phillips CD-i games"

Comment: Other than a boy waking up - which is how (almost?) every Zelda game begins - there really aren't any similarities to the plot of Ocarina of Time. There's no town by the sea, no girl "nowhere to be found", and no amnesia.

Comment: Hmm there was a Legend of Zelda game where Link wakes up from a slumber or something and has amnesia, I'm sure. In any case, it couldn't have been on the PS1, so the discussion is moot...

Comment: Thank you for comments. I checked Legend of Zelda but its not it. I will just keep on looking though. Thanks !

Comment: @AnthonyGrist - You're right. I'm thinking of Link's Awakening on the GB. Town by the sea, check. Amnesia, check. Girl gone, check, etc.

Comment: 3D? Sprites? RPG? Action? Action RPG? Also "pretty sure was PS1" could go a little more in-depth.  10 years ago from now would be 2008, 2 years after the PS3 was released, so things like controller color and system color could help in identification.  Maybe it was a Dreamcast! Language? Do you live someplace where there is a less-than-legal manner in obtaining games?

Comment: Are you sure it was PS1? I still have a PS1, but ten years ago would be well past the time you'd commonly see them.

Comment: The amnesia aspect and mention of the sea sounds a little like "ICO" to me, which was PS2 rather than PS1; it would have been re-released as a budget edition around the time OP mentions.

Comment: I think the game you are looking for is called Alundra

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could this be [Chrono Cross](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chrono_Cross)?

It's a PS1 game. Graphics are roughly similar to Kingdom Hearts. There's only two years between the game, but KH1 is on the PS2. Regardless, if this looks similar to KH1, it is likely a late-gen PS1 game.

> there is a boy (main character) and a girl in a town near a sea

The boy could be Serge, the main character of the game. He lives in a small fishing village - not quite a town, but it is on the sea. The girl could be his girlfriend, Leena. At the start of the game, he goes hunting for scales to make a necklace for her, and then meets her at the beach.

> then suddenly tragedy happened. When the boy woke up, the girl is nowhere to find

This is a bit iffier. A [cutscene](https://youtu.be/p4hMaQG5efo?t=225) plays during this scene (until 4:34), which includes flashbacks to Serge being attacked by a panther as a child, and a wave washes over him. He collapses to the floor. He wakes up to an old man finding him on the beach, with Leena not in sight.

> and the boy had an amnesia

This doesn't really match at all. I think Serge does have memory loss regarding the panther attack as a child, but I don't think that would have been in the introduction.

He did travel to an alternate timeline in that cutscene, and as a result his memory becomes different from reality, but that's not really amnesia.

Comment: This was my first thought as well.

Comment: I think it is Chrono Cross. thank you very much !

Answer (score 2):

If it's not *Chrono Cross*, the game might have been *[Galerians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galerians)*.

The beginning of the plot summary from Wikipedia:

> Galerians begins with the protagonist, Rion, awaking in a hospital observation room, unable to remember his identity. He hears a girl's voice calling to him in his mind, begging him to come to her rescue, and he decides to search for her. Using psychokinetic abilities to escape his room, Rion fights hospital security and staff desperately and brutally with his newly discovered psychic powers. He finds that human experiments related to unlocking psychic potential are being conducted in the hospital as part of a grander, more mysterious plan known as the "G Project."

A lot of people have been killed, but he is still looking for a missing girl who will help him prevent humanity from being totally destroyed.  I don't think there's anything about being near the sea though.

Here are a trailer and the opening video: